# XmlSerializer - object to string returning "p2:nill" instead of xsi:nill

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, xsi

After Serialzation, object to a string

I am getting the current xml

```
  <obj>
    ...
    <field p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    ...
  </obj>
```

the field is nullable so i am waiting for an **xsi:nill**, 
instead i am getting **p2:nill** why?

Comment: Can you post your object?

Comment: They are effectively the same thing the `xsi` is just a name, it just happens to be the commony used one for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

Comment: You don't need it to say `xsi`. The `p2` in your example is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When building an XmlSerializer you can control the namespaces, if you don't random(ish) names will be applied. Try seeing if something like this helps

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AnEntity));
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new AnEntity(), ns);
```